# How does proof-of-stake handle a denial-of-service attack?

Tags: proof-of-stake, attacks

As I understand it, the current proof-of-stake model works where one validator proposing a new block, and the block is accepted if enough validators approve it.

What happens if someone performs a DoS attack to knock most of the validators offline?  I presume the attacker can't simply force invalid blocks through by outnumbering the surviving honest validators -- that's too obvious of an attack for the developers not to have though of it.  Does the network simply grind to a halt until the attack ends, or is there some mitigation in place?

Answer (score 0):

https://certik.medium.com/what-is-a-ddos-attack-how-can-it-affect-crypto-4f62cc1cad8c

With the rise of applications of blockchain technology, a new type of DoS attack emerged — a blockchain denial-of-service (BDoS) attack. These attacks focus on blockchains operating under the proof-of-work (PoW)consensus mechanism like Bitcoin.

Attacks in Crypto

In February of 2021, the EXMO Cryptocurrency exchange fell victim to a DDoS attack that rendered the organization inoperable for almost five hours.
**Solana network went down for around four hours early this month as a result of an apparent DDoS attack. Solana.Status showed the network has been fully operational with 100% uptime over that period.**
Arbitrum One had a transaction flood overwhelm the Sequencer, knocking it offline for approximately 45 minutes. Without the Sequencer, transactions were waiting in the queue but no new transactions were being accepted or being added to the blockchain.
Unfortunately, cryptocurrency exchanges have become increasingly targeted by DDoS attacks because of their growing popularity. Since 2020, there have been numerous DDoS attack attempts on some of the major crypto exchanges. Unfortunately, this renders the exchange’s services unavailable for a prolonged period of time.

Comment: Interesting information, but I don't see how this answers the question about PoS validator DDoS